# Delete Excel Rows if They Do Not Contain a Specific String in a Cell

Tags: string, excel, delete-row, vba

I have an excel file where on the 3d (C) column cells, there is a text. If the cell string **does not** contain : "(DELETED)", I want the entire row to be deleted. I tried the following code and it works but as far as concerned the syntax, it needs to be edited.

[image: Print Screen of the Excel file]

```
Sub sbDelete_Rows_IF_Cell_Contains_Specific_String()
 Dim lRow As Long
 Dim iCntr As Long
 lRow = 5
  For iCntr = lRow To 1 Step -1
    celltxt = Cells(iCntr, 3).Value
    If InStr(1, celltxt, "(DELETED)") Then

    Else
     Rows(iCntr).Delete
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

If the script finds the cells that contain the string : "(DELETED)", then the program will not do anything. It will delete the ones that do not contain this string. The syntax is bad and I wonder how I can combine the "InStr" and the "IF NOT" functions.

Comment: The InStr function returns an integer indicating the position the text can be found at. Even though it may work as a boolean, I would advise you tp check if the instr function returns a 0 (not found) or a positive number (found). In your case it is probably sufficient to have Instr(1, celltxt, ""(Deleted)") = 0 in the if statement and then deleting the row.

Comment: Change `If InStr(1, celltxt, "(DELETED)") Then` to `If Not InStr.....` and get rid of the `Else`. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @nhee "If Not" did not work for me. Maybe it was a bug though. The files are quite big.

Comment: @Tom Excellent. The description covered me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tom mentioned, it returns an integer, so it'd be easier doing something like this, rather than using a `NOT`

```
Sub test()
Dim lrow As Integer
lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = lrow To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Cells(i, 3), "(DELETED)") = 0 Then
        Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Perfect. What does the "A" stand for?

Comment: "A" is the column letter that it counts.

Comment: It can be anything I presume. It will work for "B" as well. Is it ok to use "ws.Rows.Count" instead?

Comment: Yes you can specify any column letter. If you need to make the code more specific with source worksheets and targets, that should work as well.

Comment: I get a runtime error 424 when I use the ws.Rows.Count or the Rows.Count